Doubt on characterization of continuity
I am reading "General Topology" of Willard and a step in the most famous characterization of continuity is getting under my skin. The theorem states:

If $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau')$ are topological spaces and $f \: : \: X \rightarrow Y$, then the following are equivalent:
$(i)$ $f$ is continuous
$(ii)$for each open set $H$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(H)$ is an open set in $X$.

To see $(i)\implies(ii)$. We suppose $f$ continuous, let $A$ open in $(Y,\tau')$, ¿is $f^{-1}(A)$ open in $(X,\tau)$? This is the same as saying $f^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(A)º$, that is, every point is an interior point. Let $x \in f^{-1}(A)$, then $f(x) \in A$. So, A is an open nhood of $f(x)$ in $Y$. As $f$ is continuous, we have that there exists $U$ nhood of $x$ in $X$ such that $f(U)\subset A$. Therefore,$U \subset f^{-1}(A)$. This means that every $x \in f^{-1}(A)$ is an interior point, so $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$.
I lack to understand the step that states $U \subset f^{-1}(A)$. I mean,we have $f(U) \subset A$. Then applying $f^{-1}$ we have $f^{-1}(f(U)) \subset f^{-1}(A)$. We know that $f^{-1}(f(U)) \subset U$ but this doesn't imply $U \subset f^{-1}(A)$. Can somebody give me some hint on what I am missing please.
For completeness of the question I prove $(ii) \implies (i)$. We suppose that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$, for all $A$ open in $Y$. ¿is $f$ continuous? Let $x \in X$ and $V$ a nhood of $f(x)$ in $Y$, then there exists $A$ open set of $Y$ such that $f(x) \in A \subset V$. As $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$ and $x \in f^{-1}(A)$, we have that there exists $U=f^{-1}(A)$ open nhood of $x$ in $X$ such that $f(U) \subset f(f^{-1}(A)) \subset A \subset V$. Then, f is continuous $\forall x \in X$.
I'd really appreciate any hint in the step I'm missing. Hope you are doing great and thanks for your time!

How does the book define continuity of a function?

@DanAsimov $f$ is continuous at $x_0 \in X$ iff for each nhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$ in $Y$, there is a nhood $U$ of $x_0$ in X such that $f(U) \subset V$. Then $f$ is continuous in $X$ iff $f$ is continuous at each $x_0 \in X$

$f^{-1}(f(U)) \supset U$ not the other way around

It is true (for general sets and mappings) that if $f(U)\subseteq A$, then $U\subseteq f^{-1}(A).$
Consider an arbitrary $u\in U.$ Then $f(u)\in f(U)\subseteq A,$ so $f(u)\in A.$ Thus $u\in f^{-1}(A) := \{p\in X: f(p)\in A\}.$ Since $u\in U$ was arbitrary, $U\subseteq f^{-1}(A).$
